# Creating a path for new document

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating some pictures in the "Pictures" directory.
I would like to increment the name of each picture added by 1... Untitled 001, Untitled 002, Untitled 003 etc

I am trying it like this. Every time I create the picture, myPicNumber increments like so:

```
 myPicNumber = myPicNumber + 1;

 NSString* string = NSHomeDirectory();

 NSString* pth1 = [string stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Pictures/Untitled.png"];
```

How do I code this @"/Pictures/Untitled.png"]; to do the incrementation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use stringWithFormat!

Comment: Thanks, works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Pictures/Untitled%d.png", myPicNumber];
```

Comment: Thanks, that's how I did it.